# Using SpringBoot, NodeJS and Vue-CLI - not saved session

Tags: spring-boot, vue-cli

I have been using SpringBoot for web development before, which needs to manage session, database, HTML and other functions.
Recently, I am going to use VUE, replacing the HTML part of SpringBoot.
Now I use the following two methods for development, but I am troubled by problems such as cross domain and session cannot be keeped.

1. Use nodejs as the enter of the website and use vue.config to configure the  agent. In this way, the URL located is correct, but the login status cannot be saved.For example, if submit a form for login, the background returns to the successful message for login, but if refresh the page, it will show 'not login'. The 'devServer' configuration is as follows

```
     devServer: {
          open: false,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080,
        proxy: {
        '/ API: {
        Target: 'http://192.168.9.211/',
        ChangeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
        PathRewrite: {
        '^ / API' : ' '
        },
        cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost',
        }
        }
        }
```

2. Use Nginx as gateway, and then forward the HTML request to NodeJS, and the data request (such as JSON data) to SpringBoot.I haven't had time to experiment with this idea, because it may still occur session saving issues.Nginx is forwarding HTTP requests to Nodejs and SpringBoot, so this saved session is from Nodejs or SpringBoot?

So ask if anyone has done a similar project and if you can share your experience.